# How to run a bash shell script from a html button click?

Tags: bash, scripts, html

If I have a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ./test.txt
```

that I want to be activated on the push of a button on any simple html page how would I go about this?

html looking something like this (tho i know it's wrong)

```
<form action="./test.sh">
        <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
 </form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Comment: I'm getting a "Cannot GET /test.php" when i push the button

Comment: From the context of the page running on a server as is normal with most websites, or a page running locally just on your own machine?  On a server, use a server-side language to execute the script, e.g. PHP in Apache, a JSP(Java) in an app server.  Locally, the browser security model should prevent you from actually executing anything on the local machine.